# how to texturize correctly an interior using ONLY the reference image with which it has been created

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, shaders, uv-image-editor

This interior :

[image]

is a 3D representation of this reference image :

[image: interior image reference]

I would like to learn how to texturize it also exactly. It means that I would like to know what's the workflow that should I use if I want to convert the only reference Image that I have into the needed textures to reproduce exactly its look.

On youtube I found a tool and a tutorial that teach how to convert a single image into its textures,it's called "**Materialize -- An AMAZING Free Texture Map Generating Tool**" Please give a look at it going [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtnJToPxBNo).

I should only give the original picture to the tool and it creates all the textures that I need : **diffuse ; edge ; height ; metallic ; normal ; smoothness**.

[image: Materialize textures]

Also,on blender 2.8 I'm using the addon "**rapid PBR material creator**",that you can find [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/RapidPBRMaterialCreator). It creates all the material nodes with one click.

The problem is that the ground does not seem like that on the original picture,I think because it's not enough to do a simple UV unwrapping :

[image: uv unwrapping]

So,what can I do here ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## That is not possible.

(in the context of a result of practical accuracy or quality)

The image you have is the result of complex light interactions with various surfaces. One image simply does not contain all the data required to reconstruct the scene at this level. Think of it this way - if you add 15 and 45, you get 60, however if I only tell you the result, there is no way for you to know it was 15 and 45 I added together, it could be 30 and 30 for example or any other numbers that make 60 when you add them together. Your image is exactly the same way only a result. It is possible to interpret the image and then reconstruct the scene using artistic interpretation, however that will require a lot of experience, guesses and additional images for texturing as well. If you have a look at the floor for example, since we are viewing it from an angle we are seeing a lot of specular reflection instead of the diffuse color of the floor - many kinds of dark brown floor could look like that from this angle. It would also be impossible to recreate the painting without even seeing it as well as many other objects.

It seems the path you are trying to take does not lead anywhere. The logical thing to do would be to reevaluate your broader situation, context and goals and see if what you are trying to do might be possible some other way.

Comment: I've used materialize to convert the original picture into the correct image textures,infact its name is "image to material tool". In my case I tried to use the color texture generated by this tool. But when I have created the nodes with the Rapid PBR addon,the look has not been good. where is the error in this workflow ? maybe I'm using materalize in the wrong way ?

Comment: The workflow when using tools like Materialize or Substance B2M usually is to generate textures from photographs of the materials in controlled lighting environments. A photo studio for example is a good place to get the needed flat and even lighting. The one low resolution photo you have simply does not contain enough detail and is not suitable for this.

Comment: "everything" is clear. thanks.

Comment: I wish I could be more constructive here, but it is what it is. This is a constant struggle - I render interior design visualizations for a living and it is a constant search for good resources or ways to make them. This is one of the main problems at this job (at least for me) - how to get or make good textures for the specific materials required by the clients. Unfortunately, it is also often part of interior designer's job to make every interior unique, so often they literally work hard to come up with something new for me to do every time. It's not an easy problem you are facing here.

Comment: yes,I understand. It makes sense. But I think that what you say is valid only if we want to reach the photorealism,right ?

Comment: And that makes it valid in the 'PBR' workflow and in the context of rendering with light interacting with materials that have different surface properties so basically in the whole thing completely. It is not valid if you wish to transfer shade-less colors to 3d objects and make some kind of 3d effects that way and if you do not care about the quality of the already low resolution image degrading even further or if you wish non-photo-realistic results like cell shading style or something like that.

Comment: yeah. I don't want photorealism. And I don't like to use the degraded pictures as they seem to be now. So,I want to colorize them them in some artistic way. U talked about cell shading. It's interesting for me. Do u know any other way to re-utilize them in a good way ?

Comment: Not really. This is a bit too abstract for me to think of any advice. It is up to you to decide what you want.